# Html & Php Contact Form with Email Submission

Tags: php, jquery, html

Db Connection

```
$server     = 'localhost:8080';
$username   = 'root';
$password   = '';
$database   = 'resort';
$connect    = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password ) or die(mysqli_error.'error connecting to db');

//select database
mysqli_select_db ($database, $connect) or die(mysqli_error.'error selecting db');

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $message    = $_POST['message'];
    $filtered_email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($message))
    {
      //insert the data into DB
      mysql_query("INSERT into contactform (contact_id, contact_name, contact_email, contact_phone, message )
                VALUES ('', '".$name."',
               '".$email."', '".$phone."',
               '".$message."' )") or die(mysqli_error());

        //prepare email headers
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=isoo-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: ".$email."\r\n";
        $to = 'mahesh.gulve004@gmail.com,'.$email;
        $subject = 'Contact Form';
        $body       = 'From: <br/> Name: '.$name.' <br/>E-mail: '.$email.'<br/>Phone: '.$phone.'<br/>Message: '.$message;

         //before sending the email make sure that the email address is correct
        if ( $filtered_email == false ) {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'error' => true,
                'msg'   => "The email address entered it's not correct!"
            ));
            exit;
        }
        $mail       = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

        //finally send the email
        if ( $mail ) {
            //finally send the ajax response
            echo json_encode(array(
                'error' => false
            ));
            exit;
        } else {
            //finally send the ajax response
            echo json_encode(array(
                'error' => true,
                'msg'   => "Opss...Something went wrong. Message was not sent!"
            ));
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'error' => true,
            'msg'   => "You haven't completed all required fileds!"
        ));
        exit;
   }
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  //CONTACT FORM AJAX SUBMIT
  $('#send').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'mailer.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        if (data.error === true) {
          $('#error').css('display', 'block');
          var error = document.getElementById('error');
          error.innerHTML = data.msg;
          setTimeout(function() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 1);
          }, 100);
        } else {
          $('#note').show();
          $('#error').hide();
          $("#fields").hide();
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div id="test-form" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide" style="width:400px;float:left;">
    <div id="formcontent">
      <div id="formheader" style="border-bottom:1px solid #e3e3e3;margin-bottom:20px;">
        <h1 style="color:#37bc9b;font-size:33px;">We will get back to you...</h1>
      </div>
      <fieldset style="border:0;">
        <div id="note">
          <h2>Message sent successfully!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-form">
          <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <span id="name-info" class="info">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="name" name="name" class="form-control demoInputBox">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <span id="email-info" class="info">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="email" name="email" class="form-control demoInputBox">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                  <span id="phone-info" class="info">
                    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control demoInputBox">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="message">Message</label>
                  <span id="message-info" class="info">
                    <textarea placeholder="" rows="5" id="message" name="message" class="form-control demoInputBox">
                    </textarea>
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-info" id="send" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
              </form>
            </div>
         </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="error"></div>
```

Issue is that when I click on submit the data is not submitted in fact I will say nothing happens by clicking submit button. Errors does not occur so no way to find out what the problem is. I am trying to build a contact form that can send mail. So you will also get some code related to it.

Comment: I am not quite sure if the `$(this).serialize()` is working in this part. Because it is not the form itself but the submit button. Are you sure you are not receiving any errors and no request is beeing send?

Comment: yes sir no errors and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

To submit the form you should use:

```
 $('#contactForm').submit(function(){

    //your ajax function

     return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try $("#contactForm").serialize() instead of $(this).serialize()